# MS Access 2019 - questions about editing and running SQL queries

Tags: microsoft-access, sql

In the past I've worked with SQL Server and PostgreSQL, using SQL to run queries. At the moment I'm trying to get more familiar with MS Access, and I run into some problems. I prefer to write queries directly in an editor, and I'm having trouble getting the interface do what I want. Maybe it's a question of getting used to, maybe I'm missing some features.

1. Sometimes I don't see the RUN button. I would like it to be present all the time when I'm in the SQL view, editing a query.
2. I would like to have the editor always present, next to the results. Now it disappears when I run a query.
3. If possible I would like to see the table structure as well.
4. The editor seems to lack color formatting, and automatic indenting. Can this be enabled, or is it possible to use another editor, maybe even an external editor?

Any comments, suggestions, or links to articles that explain this are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin that costs $10 and inserts a complete SQL editor with all expected functionality in it. I decided to buy that. Any other suggestions are appreciated.

https://fieldeffect.info/wp/downloads/access-sql-editor/